# Do html5-compliant parsers process html 4 and older correctly?

Tags: html, parsing, backwards-compatibility, html4

Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup#HTML5 it's written:

> HTML5 aims to be the most complete solution to the problem of tag soup
>   thus far while remaining as backwards- and forwards-compatible as
>   possible. By contrast to XHTML, which departs from backwards
>   compatibility and takes the approach that parsers should become less
>   tolerant of badly formed markup, HTML5 acknowledges that badly formed
>   HTML code already exists in large quantities and will probably
>   continue to be used, and takes the view that the specification should
>   be expanded to ensure maximum compatibility with such code.
>
> Thus, the HTML 5 specification has altered its definition of HTML
>   syntax both to accommodate common syntax in use today, and to
>   explicitly describe exactly how "badly formed code" should be treated
>   by the parser. The handling of badly formed code now has a place in
>   the specification itself, hopefully reducing the need for future HTML
>   parsers to implement additional, out-of-specification measures for
>   dealing with code that it does not recognize.

Do I understand right then that a html5 parser should parse older html pages (like html 2.0 or html 4) correctly? I need a html parser that would parse normally most of internet pages. So I found Google Gumbo: https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser. It's written there that it's HTML5 parser. Will it suit me then to parse not html5 web pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's one of the main differences between HTML5 and XHTML. You should be able to parse any HTML page with a HTML5 parser.